# Clear shell history on shutdown/logout

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I want to clear my shell history on every shutdown/logout.

I know how to clear the history manually, I know how to clear the history automatically, when closing the session/terminal emulator. However, this is not the intended behaviour.

I am using `zsh` on manjaro with wayland and sway.

I have tried using .zlogout. However, this did not work, as far as I understand, because it is ment for login shells (I don't know what makes a login shell).

Comment: History is saved only if you ask the shell to save it (by setting `$HISTFILE` and `$SAVEHIST` in `~/.zshrc`). Why not just not do that history saving.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas because I want to save history during one session (I often use similar commands again and again), but not over the course of several sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to use `systemd` (which manjaro should AFAIK), one option would be a simple service that just succeeds and has the history-deletion executed when it stops. Then make it depend on  `default.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Delete zsh-history on logout/shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/grbll/bin/zsh-remover.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

User services go e.g. in `~/.config/systemd/user/zsh-history-wipe.service`

For enabling it permanently and for activating it for your current session once run

```
systemctl --user enable zsh-history-wipe
systemctl --user start zsh-history-wipe
```

As all services are stopped with the last logout or on shutdown, the `ExecStop`-command will be run in the end. Obviously does not work for e.g. power outages.

Note that lingering must be disabled for the user!

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I also learned how to do similar things in the future.
I had to replace `ExecStop=/home/grbll/bin/zsh-remover.sh` by `ExecStop=/bin/zsh /home/grbll/bin/zsh-remover.sh`. Even though I used a bang tag in zsh-remover.sh.

Comment: @grbll did you set the executable bit on the script? (`chmod u+x /home/grbll/bin/zsh-remover.sh`)

Comment: yes, it is -rwxr-xr-x owned by $USR:$USR.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a shell script that clears your history and place it in a location where it will be executed on logout or shutdown. FOllow these steps:

1. The file may look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
history -c
history -w
```

2. Make the file executable: `chmod +x script.sh`
3. Configure your Sway (`~/.config/sway/config`) adding this command to the end of the config file: `exec /path/to/the/script.sh`

And that's it!

Comment: "I know how to clear the history manually," you're solving the problem that grbll already knows how to solve. What grbll wants to know is *where* to put this so that it gets executed on logout or shutdown! Could you maybe expand your answer on what you mean with "location where it will be executed on logout or shutdown.", because I'm myself not aware of such a location!